# template class variable as member of a non template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I'm not an expert C++ developer,
I'm not sure if is it possible to do what I want.

I have a template class like:

```
template < typename T >
class table
{
public
table ( AnotherClassPtr* handler, int s);
table<T>& operator<<(const T& table);
table<T>& operator>>( T& table);

...
}
```

I have a standard class. In this class I would like to create some members that are `table` objects. es:

```
class A{
public:
 ...
AnotherClassPtr* pointer;
table<aCertainStruct> myTable;
...
}
```

It does not work because I miss the default constructor of `table`. But I can't make a default constructor because I need to pass to the `table` class a pointer to `AnotherClassPtr`which is created in the constructor of class A just before where i would like to call the constructor I defined for `table`. es:

```
//inside the constructor of the A class.
....
pointer= getAnotherClassPtr();
table<aCertainStruct> myTable ( pointer, 42);
...
```

---

[an attempt]
The stuff below compile but it does not work as I expected. Infact if I try to call some funcions of the class table it does not work.

```
class A{
public:
 ...
AnotherClassPtr* pointer;
table<aCertainStruct> myTable ( AnotherClassPtr*, unsigned int)
...
}

// in the constructor of the A class
....
pointer= getAnotherClassPtr();
table<aCertainStruct> myTable ( pointer, 42);
...
```

### as I said this does not work;

**Q:** is it possible to create a template class variable as member of a non template class? 
Or in other workds: is it possible to  define a `table` member in the `A` class declaration and then define the table object calling my user defined constructor inside the `A` constructor?

I'm sorry for my bad english, is not my native language, I hope the problem is clear.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why there exists *constructor initializer lists*:

```
class A{
public:
    A()
        : pointer(getAnotherClassPtr()), myTable(pointer, some_value)
    {}

    ...
    AnotherClassPtr* pointer;
    table<aCertainStruct> myTable;
    ...
};
```

This will initialize and "call" the parameterised constructor of `table`, instead of the default constructor.

---

These days with a relatively modern compiler, you should also be able to do something similar to what you want in the second attempt of the `A` class, but you have to use "assignment" syntax for the initialization, or curly-braces `{}` instead of parentheses `()` (since parentheses are for member functions):

```
table<aCertainStruct> myTable{pointer, some_value};
```

This of course requires that `pointer` is initialized first.

Answer (score 1):

In simple cases like this, you can use the member initializer syntax rather than assigning to (already initialized) members.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() :
        pointer(getAnotherClassPtr()),
        myTable(pointer, 42)
    {}

    //...
    // pointer must come before myTable!
    AnotherClassPtr* pointer;
    table<aCertainStruct> mytable;
};
```

As noted in the class comment, this wouldn't work if `mytable` were declared before `pointer` in the class definition.  The order class members are initialized always depends on the order the class declared them, not the order of the constructor's member initializer list.  Also, if `getAnotherClassPtr` is a member of `A`, make sure it's either marked `static` or it doesn't use any other members of `A` declared before `pointer`, for the same reason.

If you have other reasons to want class members declared in a certain order, or if the initialization logic is more complicated in other ways, a more general solution to this sort of issue is to use a private helper struct and delegate to a private constructor:

```
class A
{
private:
    struct InitHelper;
public:
    A() : A(InitHelper()) {}
    // ...

    // Now member order doesn't matter.
    table<aCertainStruct> mytable;
    AnotherClassPtr* pointer;
    // ...

private:
    explicit A(InitHelper&& helper);
};

struct A::InitHelper
{
    AnotherClassPtr* pointer;
    unsigned int mytable_arg2;
    InitHelper();
};

inline A::InitHelper::InitHelper()
{
    // Actual logic here!
    // ...
    pointer = getAnotherClassPtr();
    mytable_arg2 = 42;
    // ...
}

inline A::A(InitHelper&& helper) :
    mytable_arg2(helper.pointer, helper.mytable_arg2),
    pointer(helper.pointer)
{}
```